# how to replace old table rows with new rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, html-table, dynamic-tables

I have created a dynamic table in html [click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlZIP.png) the rows are created dynamically in javascript please refer the image [click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCgcN.png) the data for table is fetched from firebase.

The problem I am facing is that the rows are getting added at the end of the table repeatedly resulting in duplicate rows please refer the image [click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Ei5.png) how do I remove old rows and add new updated rows using javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow! Please don't post pictures of code. Post your code as properly formatted text into the question. Before doing so read this: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the `snapshot.forEach` loop with comments.

```
snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
    var val = data.val();

    var trow = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdata = document.createElement('td');
    var tdata1 = document.createElement('td');

    tdata.innerHTML = val.Name;
    tdata1.innerHTML = val.Votes;

    trow.appendChild(tdata);
    trow.appendChild(tdata1);

    // set the Name as data-id attribute
    // which can be used to query the existing row
    tdata.setAttribute('data-id', val.Name);

    // append the trow to tbdy
    // only if there's no row with data-id value of val.Name
    // otherwise update the vote column of the existing row
    var existingRow = tbdy.querySelector('[data-id="' + val.Name + '"]');
    if (!existingRow) {
        tbdy.appendChild(trow);
    } else {
        existingRow.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerHTML = val.Votes;
    }
});
```